# Is there a commodity 3 or 4 way valve that can be electrically controlled?

Tags: plumbing, valve, irrigation

I live out here in the San Francisco bay area where it doesn't rain in the summer. So I want to make an automated plant watering device.

I already have a water pump intended for solar water heating that pumps from a 2 gallon jug to 3 pots on the railing. I also split the flow from 1 tube into 3, but this isn't working well because the flow becomes uneven between the 3.

I could build 2 more independent pumps, but that would get too complicated if I wanted to water > 3 plants.

So, is there a commodity valve that can switch the flow between 3 or more destinations and can be controlled electronically?

The seal doesn't have to withstand high pressures since the pump I use can barely push water up 3 feet.

Comment: A [Zone Valve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zone_valve) might be overkill :)

Comment: Zone valve, starting at $16 on ebay, me, idle time, and home automation.  Simply Genius!    My wife is going to kill you :)))

Answer (score 2):

I use a multi-port automatic sprinkler valve coupled to an 8-way drip irrigation manifold, and use city water pressure.

Answer (score 1):

Since the question is 'can', and the situation is not a major threat to safety or welfare of people and property, in similar circumstances, a 'friend' of mine used solenoid lawn sprinkler valves.

$10 what is not to like.
http://www.sprinklerwarehouse.com/Signature-Sprinkler-Valve-Solenoid-p/7962.htm

My friend got his at Home Depot - but I could not find them on their web site.

As a note - do not use this as an air valve release for a potato cannon. (I am not saying it can not do the job - but I am saying do not do it.)

Comment: OK, that would work, but it's almost as bulky/redundant as having multiple pumps (the pump I'm using might be smaller than that solenoid valve). I was hoping for something that's more compact like a 6-shooter with a tube connected to each of the chambers and rotated by a servo.

Comment: I would love a small servo thing too, not sure what I would do with it, but I love the idea :)   OK, what about something like this a 3 way hose manifold, they come in sizes from fish tank air hose, to garden hose, each outlet has a valve, and then adjust the flow for each plant pot.  "  Orbit 3-Way Plastic Hose Faucet Valve Manifold 62009  "  still not what you are looking for, but maybe to hold you over until you find something else

Comment: A really small pump for each plant - 5W, 12VDC and submersible ASIN number B00JWJIC0K